# Does CUDA mapped memory take up GPU RAM?

Tags: memory-management, cuda

For example, if I have a GPU with 2GB RAM and in my app allocate large array, like 1GB, as mapped memory (page-locked host memory that is mapped to GPU address space, allocated with `cudaHostAlloc()`), will the amount of available GPU memory be reduced for that 1GB of mapped memory, or will I still have (close to) 2GB as I had before allocation and use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mapping host memory so that it appears in the GPU address space does not consume memory from the GPU on-board memory.

You can verify this in a number of ways, such as using [cudaMemGetInfo](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gd5d6772f4b2f3355078ecd6059e6aa74)